# Calculate angle between two coordinates? Python

Tags: python, math, coordinates, angle

Say you have two coordinates within a range of 0.0 till 1.0.
A: (0.12, 0.75)
B: (0.43, 0.97)
And you want to walk from point A to point B. How would you calculate the angle in python.Where north is 0 and south is 180.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to get it from North then here you go:

```
def get_angle(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return math.degrees(math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1))
```

This works because

```
tan(x) = Opposite/Adjacent;
Opposite/Adjacent = (x2-x1)/(y2-y1);
x=atan(x2-x1, y2-y1)
```

With `atan` being the inverse of `tan`. And to not just get the orientation, but true direction, we use the [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function instead, as that can get use angels from -pi (-180) to +pi (180), whereas `atan` can only yield values between -pi/2 (-90) and pi/2 (90).

One gotcha: the argument order for `atan2` is the y difference *first*, so it's `atan2(dy, dx)`, *not* `atan2(dx, dy)`.

Comment: Note: `atan` doesn't give the correct result. `atan2` is the correct function. atan give just the orientation of the path, but not the direction

Comment: don't ```math.atan((x2-x1)/(y2-y1))``` and ```math.atan2((x2-x1),(y2-y1))```do the same thing?

Comment: No, On the first you lose the sign: both positive or both negative will give you the same result, so you have only 180degree result. On the second part, you get all 360 degree angles (because you known the sector you are). Just try with (1,1), (-1,-1), (1,-1), (-1,1)

Comment: Oh, I see now. Yeah sorry about that I didn't know ```atan``` only returned-90 to 90. I'll change the answer now

Comment: but so, put a `,` and remove the `/`

Comment: *"Opposite/Adjacent = x2-x1/y2-y1"* I believe you forgot important parentheses on that line.

Comment: Also note that `atan2` does _not_ use the `(x,y)` ordering of its arguments that plain `atan` does. The signature is `atan2(dy, dx)`, with the y difference _first_, not second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works quite good., except in some cases When I try to find the angle between coordinates (0.4851, 0.5384) and (0.4895, 0.5346) it gives 49 as a result in stead of 60 (the correct angle). How can this be? for other angles it is okay. My function is ```def angle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1)) + 90 ; if angle < 0:  angle = 270 + abs(angle) ; return angle```

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the diference in x and the diference in y and use the function `math.atan2(y/x)` from the `math` module. Then it's just a matter of converting from radians to degrees and add 90º.

Comment: `math.atan2` is much better suited than `math.atan` for this task. Read about it on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant atan2, I just research about atan2 before posting but forgot the 2 in atan2

Comment: But then it's `atan2(x, y)`, not `atan2(y/x)`